# Producing an array in terminal that overwrites previous board

Tags: c++, arrays

My goal is to have an array and print this array in console and have user input to modify this board - I got this all working - but now I want to overwrite the previous board so that it looks like it is one continuous board being modified.

So I want my array to look like the following:

```
[1, 1, 1]    [2, 2, 2]
[2, 2, 2] -> [1, 1, 1]
[3, 3, 3]    [3, 3, 3]
```

All over the same 3 lines on console. I am quite sure I am to use `carriage` which I know how to do for a single line but I am not familiar with using `carriage` for multiple lines.

I tried setting it up so that each line overwrites itself but it doesn't appear to be working.

```
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
   for(int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
      std::cout << board[i][j];
   }
   std::cout << "\r";
}
```

Comment: you can find answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/29344604/1327005

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can try to print a large number of new lines and reprint the array to give the illusion of it just changing. Here is a simple game of "15 puzzle" I wrote with this technique for you to see the idea:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
#define SZ 4

void printArray(string a[][SZ])
{ std::cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
    for (int i=0; i<SZ; ++i)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<SZ; ++j)
        {
            std::cout<< a[i][j] <<"\t";
        }
        std::cout<<"\n\n\n";
    }

std::cout<<"\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n";
}

int main()
{
    string a[SZ][SZ] ={
    {"5","2","4","12"},
        {"6","8","10","1"},
        {"9","7"," ","15"},
        {"13","14","3","11"}};

    string choice;

    int x=2; //first coordinate of empty space
    int y=2; //second coordinate of empty space
    while(true)
    {
        printArray(a);
        cin>>choice;

        if(choice=="w")
        {
            //space has to move up
            if(x>0) //can still move up
            {
                string tmp=a[x-1][y];
                a[x-1][y]=" ";
                a[x][y]=tmp;
                x--;
            }
        }
        else if (choice=="a")
        {
            //space has to move left
            if(y>0)
            {
                string tmp=a[x][y-1];
                a[x][y-1]=" ";
                a[x][y]=tmp;
                y--;
            }

        }
        else if (choice=="s")
        {
            //space has to move down
            if(x<SZ-1)
            {
                string tmp=a[x+1][y];
                a[x+1][y]=" ";
                a[x][y]=tmp;
                x++;
            }

        }
        else if(choice=="d")
        {
            //space has to move right
             if(y<SZ-1)
             {
                 string tmp=a[x][y+1];
                 a[x][y+1]=" ";
                 a[x][y]=tmp;
                 y++;
             }
        }
        else
        {
        cout<<"invalid input!\n";
        }

    }


    return 0;
}
```